# How to create chart with table in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

Is it possible to develop a chart along with a table as a single control in SSRS?

If possible can somebody tell me how to get it? I mean what type of chart we need to select and all.

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

You can do this simply by adding a DataSet to your report that includes all the data required for your chart and your report.  Add a Chart control to your report and point the datasource to your dataset.  You can use the chart wizard to choose the chart type.  Then add a table control to your report and point it to the same dataset.  I hope this helps.

Comment: ofcourse i'm doing same, but in that case these two controls are different and indipendent controls. But I want both in a single control. Anyhow thank you for your reply

Answer (score 2):

Link below shows some ways to accomplish what you are looking for.  Search for "Adding Chart Data Tables"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964128(v=sql.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can place chart objects in a table (or list, matrix, etc).

This way you could, for example, display a chart at the end of the detail rows for each grouping.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this simply by adding a DataSet to your report that includes all the data required for your chart and your report. Add a Chart control to your report and point the datasource to your dataset. You can use the chart wizard to choose the chart type. Then add a table control to your report and point it to the same dataset. I hope this helps.